# Looking for suggestions on how to re-arrange this kitchen layout, refrigerator too close to window

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator, kitchen-sink, design, layout

I am in the process of re-designing my kitchen layout, and my current design is exactly 159 inches on the right side. Unfortunately, the distance between the top wall and the right window is exactly 159 inches, and I'm placing the refrigerator next to the window.

Is there a way to re-arrange this kitchen so that I can save a few inches on the right side?

Some ideas I have are

1. reducing the size of the sink cabinet from 36 inch to 33 inches
2. Don't center the kitchen sink, move sink to the right, and move the dishwasher to the left side.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Kitchen layout]
[image]

Comment: I would reduce the width of the wall & base cabinet that would be to the left of the refrigerator.

Comment: Corners are hard. You generally want a lazy susan in the corner (been that way in every house I lived in, not much else to do with a corner).  The dishwasher crowding the corner creates a huge "dead space" to its left.  If it **must** be there-ish, I'd twist it 45 degrees so the dead space left and right of it is wedge shaped and easier to access.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Change the 27" upper (Yellow) to a 24"   Change the 18" base to a 15"

Your refrigerator is now 3 inches from the window.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however that 18-in cabinet contains the trash pull out. If I remove that where do you think I should put it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the rightmost cabinets, W2715 and BWBREP9.  Move the fridge against the dishwasher.  Add a tall narrow broom closet or pantry between the fridge and the window.  Hopefully your cabinet line has such a thing available, but if not, the closet doesn't need to be an exact match ... find anything with a very similar door in the width  you want and put it there.  The "con" of this one is you lose 15 inches of counter space.  But I think it's a better look than having the fridge wall next to the window.

**OR**

Just make the right-most cabinets narrower.  Instead of 18 below and 27 above, make them 15 below and 24 above.   If it's not a custom cabinet line, most cabinet lines come in 15 and 24 inch widths.  Hopefully yours does.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion however that 18-in cabinet contains the trash pull out drawer. if I remove that where do you suggest I put it instead?

Comment: Trash pullouts are overrated in general, and between the fridge and sink is a terrible place for one anyway.  While you are cooking, if you keep it closed you have to constantly open and close it with your wet dirty hands, or you have to keep a trash bowl in the sink or on the counter, or if you keep the pullout open it's in your way all the time.   I suggest you put a nice attractive metal pedal garbage can at the end of the peninsula where it's not in the way and is easy for everyone to find and use, and when cooking you can slide it over next to the sink.

Comment: Honestly I agree with you. Functionally a stand alone trash can makes more sense. But it seems like almost everyone is including one in their new or remodeled kitchens these days.

Comment: I mirror jay613s comments.  Most people that I have put theses trash bins in for have had regrets for some reason or another.   That includes my wife.  We relegated our trash bin to recycling and put a trash can in the pantry.

Comment: "...almost everyone is including one in their new or remodeled kitchens these days"   Here is the opportunity to not make the same mistake others have made in the name of kitchen fashion.

Comment: There are a lot of bad kitchen trends.  Built in trash is one.  Doorless cupboards, pots and pans hanging from the ceiling, counter-depth fridges, ceramic tile countertops, motion-sensing soap dispensers, .... the list goes on.  First be a slave to function, then try to make it look as nice as you can.